# Host Asp.Net MVC in IIS hides Views-Folders and .cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

When I host my Asp.Net MVC inside my default IIS, it does neither show .cshtml files, nor the Views folder at all. Even when directory browsing, these folders are missing. If I create some file in the Views folder I cannot access it either. If I create some file in another folder I can access it.
[image]

This is my routing configuration
[image]

---

I think this should be a rather basic setup question. Do I have to manually add MVC support?
My IIS is running in my docker container on the basis of windowsservercore. Setup as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell"]
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \  
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
```

Comment: I bet this is a routing issue. Can you post your routing configuration?

Comment: When I usually execute it as a WebRole within AzureStack it always ran without errors. I did not change routing. Is the situation different when I publish into folder now?

Comment: BaluJr. - But you can navigate to the root of your web app without issue?

Comment: Nope this is another issue... When I am in directory browsing and click "go to parentfolder" it gives the same errormessage as above instead showing the root folder. It further tries to go to `login.aspx` instead `login.cshtml` what would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing doesn't go to *views* it goes to *controllers*. It is the controllers that process and then render the views. Additionally, there is **no physical correlation** between the URL that you provide and the view location - that is entirely based on how the routes are setup.

It is normal and expected behavior for IIS to block direct access to the `Views` folder, since these are never used by the browser directly.

The Views are convention-based by default. The convention they use is `Views\<ControllerName>\<ActionName>.cshtml`. When a view is in the correct corresponding location, the action method can simply `return View();` and the view will be rendered.

The view `Views\tst.cshtml` will *only* be rendered if you have passed the virtual location of the view to the `View` method (for example, `return View("~/Views/tst.cshtml");`. This is because it does not match any of the "normal" MVC conventions.

Since you have not provided any examples of what your controller or action names are (or even if you have any), I will provide a basic example from the MVC template project.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

With the above controller and the `Default` route, if you pass the URL `/Home/About` (Home matching HomeController, and About matching the About method), the About method will run, and the view at `\Views\Home\About.cshtml` will be rendered.

Reference: [Understanding Models, Views, and Controllers (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs)

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer! And in the end quite obvious. But I am still confused, why I don't get it why it was working locally outside the docker container before. I will give it a try immediately tomorrow before I mark it as the answer.